# openwrt - RAM memory allocation

Tags: memory, openwrt, ram

Looking for some memory advice on an OpenWRT system.

I have a SKW71 module (ar9331 cpu). It has 16Mb flash and 512Mb ddr2 RAM. Images for that system do not exist. Therefore I have installed an OpenWRT image normally for the WR703N (4Mb flash, 32Mb RAM). All seem to work pretty well. Although I realise I might have to built a dedicated image at some point.

For now I would like to verify if the operating system is using all the hardware resources available.

From the mtd partitioning I can see the flash is being entirely used. See commands below. I do get art + firmware + u-boot totalling 16Mb. Fine.

I have more wonders about the RAM. [This page](https://openwrt.org/docs/techref/file_system) states that the /tmp is up to 50% the ram size. However according to the df command I only reach around 30Mb. This is far from the 256Mb I would expect.

How do I check how my RAM is allocated and used?

Should I be able to claim more memory for my /tmp?

If so how can I alter this?

Some of the commands below.
df / mtd / meminfo

```
root@OpenWrt:~# df -h
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
rootfs                   12.6M    812.0K     11.8M   6% /
/dev/root                 2.3M      2.3M         0 100% /rom
tmpfs                    29.9M    152.0K     29.7M   0% /tmp
/dev/mtdblock3           12.6M    812.0K     11.8M   6% /overlay
overlayfs:/overlay       12.6M    812.0K     11.8M   6% /
tmpfs                   512.0K         0    512.0K   0% /dev

root@OpenWrt:~# cat /proc/mtd 
dev:    size   erasesize  name
mtd0: 00020000 00010000 "u-boot"
mtd1: 0010c4d0 00010000 "kernel"
mtd2: 00ec3b30 00010000 "rootfs"
mtd3: 00c90000 00010000 "rootfs_data"
mtd4: 00010000 00010000 "art"
mtd5: 00fd0000 00010000 "firmware"

root@OpenWrt:~# cat /proc/meminfo | head
MemTotal:          61228 kB
MemFree:           41472 kB
MemAvailable:      47576 kB
Buffers:            1880 kB
Cached:             6224 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:             6172 kB
Inactive:           3948 kB
Active(anon):       2120 kB
Inactive(anon):       48 kB
```

---

EDIT 7 Month later.
Still looking for a solution for this. I went into uboot and can clearly see it using 64MB Ram. Looks like this would be the way to investigate now.

```
  BOARD: TP-Link TL-WR703N v1
    SOC: AR9330 rev. 1
    CPU: MIPS 24Kc
    RAM: 64 MB DDR2 16-bit CL3-4-4-10
  FLASH: 16 MB Winbond W25Q128
    MAC: 28:A1:EB:FD:1A:FF
 CLOCKS: CPU/RAM/AHB/SPI/REF
         400/400/200/ 25/ 25 MHz
```

Answer (score 1):

From your meminfo, MemTotal is 61228kB, only 64kB are recognized by the OpenWRT. I suspect that 64kB are somewhat coded and the RAM is not scanned.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Do you mean 64mB rather than 64kB?